# Open Office Excel - изменить значение ячейки (зависимость)

Tags: excel, open-office

Допустим есть две ячейки

**Цена**

**Статус**

Ячейка статус содержит select list в котором есть значение **Продано**

Задача:

Нужно при выборе статуса **Продано** каким-то образом обнулять ячейку с ценой, либо ставить **0** Чтобы она не учитывалась при подсчете всей суммы.

Comment: Нашел формулу, но дело в том что к списку она не может применяться, т.е цена и статус идут ввиде списков, и вторая проблема даже если бы цена небыла списком, как возратить текущее значение если статус (не является Продано ?) =IF(A1=A6;"This";IF(A1="ПРОДАНО";"-";"NORMAL")) там где NORMAL должно как-то возвращать текущее значение цены..

Comment: Непонятно.  Что мешает вместо *Normal* записать знаение ячейки с ценой? Прикрепите пример с тем, что есть, и тем, где и как хотели бы получить результат. Еще. Формула и константа (из выпадающего списка) в одной ячейке не уживатся. Замену можно сделать макросом. В *Excel* - без проблем, как в *open-office* - не скажу

Comment: Если коротко: есть две ячейки, A1, B1 в одной цены в другой статусы, допустим если в ячейке статусов, статус равен (Продано), тогда в ячеке на этом же уровне вместо цены (нужен Ноль, либо пусто).

Comment: *=ЕСЛИ(B1="Продано";0;цена)* Но если цену Вы хотите выбирать из списка или вписывать вручную, то формулы не помогут, нужен макрос обработки события листа

Comment: В этом вся и проблема, что я не очень знаком с офисов в целом. Это сложно сделать ? нужно чтобы было два списка в одном статусы в другом выбирать цену, но если статус продано то цена 0

Comment: Вообще, неправильно это. Хоть продано, хоть нет - цена товара от этого не меняется! Вы пытаетесь решить какую-то другую задачу, но описываете путь решения, который сами придумали и который, похоже, далек от оптимального. По вопросу: см. мое первое сообщение.  *open-office* с макросами плохо дружит.

Comment: Именно, Вы верно подметили, придумал другую логику, где высчитываеться тотальная сумма, сделать условие, чтобы суммировало только те цены у которые в ячейке статуса не стоит (Продано). Теперь уже задача другая, к примеру когда мы ставим продано, все ячейки по этой линии, приобретают определенный цвет.

Comment: СУММЕСЛИ, СУММЕСЛИМН. Заливка - читайте про условное форматироаниие. Без примера советовать больше нечего. Да и правильнее (для будущих поьзователей) создать отдельные воапросы по подсчету и по заливке, прикрепив к вопросам ПРИМЕРЫ. И, да, не путайте себя и других: *Open Office.org Calc* и *Excel*  -  разные программы.